# loading notification with webview

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview

I am loading a remote URL and want to have a loading spinner to show the app is currently downloading the page. I have this so far, but it does not really get the job done.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

    //Loading Spinner
    [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Loading"];

    //Load the URL
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myURLhere.com"];
    NSURLRequest *requestURL = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:requestURL];
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //load done.
    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make your controller implements UIWebViewDelegate.

then you can display the loading indicator when

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)view
```

get called. Then stop the indicator when

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)view
```

get called